# Visual Fox Pro Syntax Error when Previewing my Report print preview

Tags: visual-foxpro

## **Hi Good day! Visual Fox Pro 9 Syntax Error

Is there someone encounter this kind of error in visual fox pro 9? Once I edit my Report file or .frx file for my print preview format and build it again, I cant preview my Print Preview Report.
I already check all the codes, and there's no wrong spelling etc...[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rx1R2.png)
Can someone help me with this problem? I already check my program file

Answer (score 2):

If you open the report in the IDE (MODIFY REPORT) and right-click, Preview, if there's a problem, the Report Designer will show what element has the problem.

Obviously, to make this useful, you'll need to set up the data the report needs before trying to preview. Sometimes, I temporarily change the call in the routine that provides the report from REPORT FORM ... to MODIFY REPORT ..., so I can just run the application, and go to where the report is generated. When the Report Designer opens, I right-click and choose Preview.

Tamar

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to create a so called Error Handler procedure in order to find the piece/line of your code that would cause the error you observed or any other, for example by using something like the examples shown in the VFP F1 Help file or running something like the following line somewhere close to the top of your "main.PRG" (i.e. the one that is the bold "main" member of yourProject.PJX):

```
ON ERROR do ErrorHandler with ERROR(), MESSAGE(), MESSAGE(1), PROGRAM(), LINENO()
```

and placing a procedure like the following example close to the bottom of your main.PRG:

```
PROCEDURE ErrorHandler
    LPARAMETERS tnError, tcMessage, tcMessage1, tcProgram, tnLineNo

    LOCAL lcErrorMessage
    lcErrorMessage = ;
        "Error No: " + TRANSFORM(m.tnError) + CRLF + ;
        "Message: " + TRANSFORM(m.tcMessage) + CRLF + ;
        "Code: " + TRANSFORM(m.tcMessage1) + CRLF + ;
        "Method: " + LOWER( TRANSFORM(m.tcProgram) ) + CRLF + ;
        "Line: " + TRANSFORM(m.tnLineNo)

    LOCAL lcLogMessage
    lcLogMessage = ;
        REPLICATE(CRLF,3) + REPLICATE("*",5) + SPACE(1) + ;
        TRANSFORM(DATETIME()) + CRLF + CRLF + ;
        m.lcErrorMessage

    LOCAL loErrorMgr as ErrorMgr OF Libs\cmMgr.vcx
    loErrorMgr = NEWOBJECT('ErrorMgr','Libs\cmMgr.vcx')

    LOCAL lcLogFile
    IF VARTYPE(m.loErrorMgr) = 'O'
        lcLogFile = m.loErrorMgr.GetErrorLogFile()
    ELSE
        lcLogFile = C_ERRORLOGFILE
    ENDIF

    TRY
        STRTOFILE(m.lcLogMessage,m.lcLogFile,1)
    CATCH
    ENDTRY

    LOCAL lcMessage
    lcMessage = ;
        "Sorry, an unexpected Error occurred" + CRLF + ;
        "and was logged."
    MESSAGEBOX(m.lcMessage, 16, C_APPNAME)
    RETURN
ENDPROC
```